# Distribution of the sumset of two GF($q$) subsets

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, sumset

First, a simple definition. The **sumset** of two subsets $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ containing $GF(q)$ elements is defined as:

$$\mathcal{S}_1 + \mathcal{S}_2 = \left\{ s_1 + s_2:s_1 \in \mathcal{S}_1,s_2 \in \mathcal{S}_2 \right\}.$$

I will also use the common definition: $g \cdot \mathcal{S}_1 = \left\{ g \cdot s_1:s_1 \in \mathcal{S}_1 \right\}$ for some $g \in GF(q)$. Note that $GF(q)$ arithmetic is assumed.

For example, assume that $q=4$ and that $\alpha$ is a primitive element GF($4$). Then:

1. $$\{ 0,\alpha \} + \{ 0,\alpha \} = \{ 0 + 0,0 + \alpha ,\alpha  + 0,\alpha  + \alpha \} = \{ 0,\alpha \}.$$
2. $$\{ 0,\alpha \} + \{ 0,1,\alpha \} = \{ 0 + 0,0 + 1,0 + \alpha ,\alpha  + 0,\alpha  + 1,\alpha  + \alpha \} = \{ 0,1,\alpha,\alpha ^2 \}.$$
3. $$\alpha  \cdot \{ 0,1,\alpha \} = \{ 0,\alpha,\alpha ^2 \}.$$

My question is as follows. Assume that the sets $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ are iid random variables containing the symbol $0$. The additional elements of each set are drawn at random (without repetition), such that each $GF(q)$ subset (containing $0$) of a given size is equiprobable. For example, if $q=4$ then there exist probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ such that:

I. $\Pr ( S_1 = \{ 0 \} ) = p_1$,

II. $\Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,1} \right\}} \right) = \Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,\alpha } \right\}} \right) = \Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,{\alpha ^2}} \right\}} \right) = {p_2},$

III. $\Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,1,\alpha } \right\}} \right) = \Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,1,{\alpha ^2}} \right\}} \right) = \Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,\alpha ,{\alpha ^2}} \right\}} \right) = {p_3},$

IV. $\Pr \left( {{S_1} = \left\{ {0,1,\alpha ,{\alpha ^2}} \right\}} \right) = {p_4}.$

In addition, $h_1$ and $h_2$ are iid random variables, distributed uniformly over the set $\left\{ {1,\alpha ,{\alpha ^2},...,{\alpha ^{q - 2}}} \right\}$ (i.e., $h_1$ and $h_2$ can be any non-zero element of GF($q$) with probability $1/(q-1)$). Denote: $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out} = {h_1} \cdot {\mathcal{S}_1} + {h_2} \cdot {\mathcal{S}_2}.$

**I want to prove** that $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$ is also distributed such that each GF($q$) subset of a given size containing $0$ is equiprobable. (As a special case, it means that I-IV above hold for $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$ with some $p_1', p_2',p_3',p_4'$).

**What I tried:**

So far I observed that $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$ sets that differ by a multiplicative factor are equiprobable, as  $g \cdot {\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}} = g \cdot {h_1} \cdot {\mathcal{S}_1} + g \cdot {h_2} \cdot {\mathcal{S}_2}$ (for some $g \in$ GF($q$)) has the same distribution as $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$, since $g \cdot h_1, g \cdot h_2$ remain uniformly distributed. In fact, this is independent of the distribution of $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$. However, I couldn't come up with an idea how to extend this relation to sets of the same size that do not differ by a multiplicative factor. In such cases one needs to show that all element-wise translations of $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$ of a given size has the same probability.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tested this with a simulation? The first thing I would look at is the case $q=8$. I suspect (based on a vague and possibly mistaken hunch I developed while studying affine geometries and related error-correcting codes) that there might be differences among sets of size four. It just seems to me that there are more ways of arriving at such a 4-set that forms a 2D subspace than there would be to arrive at random 4-sets. Geometrically this is because such 2D-subspaces can be gotten as sums of two 1D-subspaces in many different ways, and this lead to an elevated probability.

Comment: I am working on a simulation right now, I will start with your example first.

Comment: There was a time when I would have asked someone who writes MathJax code the way it's written above why they did that.  Now I know that the reason why it's written the way a lunatic would write it is that it's done by some sort of software rather than by a person.  Maybe some day the software will be civilized and as well designed as TeX and LaTeX are.  Some day..... ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: You are right, the case $q=8$ shows that $\mathcal{S}_{\rm out}$ is not distributed as $\mathcal{S}_1$. Now my question is how many subsets out of GF($q$) subsets of a given size differ by a multiplicative factor.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment above, the case $q=8$ shows that subsets of size $4$ are not equiprobable. The reason is that some such subsets are subgroups of the additive group of GF($8$). Actually, this can be shown as well for $q=5$, where subsets of size $3$ are not equiprobable.

Therefore, the sumset of two sets, where each subset is equiprobable over subsets of the same size, when weighted by uniform non-zero coefficients, does **not** necessarily lead to equiprobable subsets over subsets of the same size.

Comment: @SolidSnake: Now the answer is stated more accurately.